# Why is TreeSet<T> an internal type in .NET?

Tags: .net, generics, collections, binary-tree

So, I was just digging around Reflector trying to find the implementation details of HashSet (out of sheer curiosity based on the answer to another question here) and noticed the following:

```
internal class TreeSet<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection,
    IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback
```

Without looking too deep into the details, it looks like a Self-Balancing Binary Search Tree.

My question is, is there anybody out there with the insight as to why this class is `internal`? Is it simply because the other collection types use it internally and hide the complexities of a BST from the general masses...or am I way off base?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exposing a type publicly involves a lot more work than only exposing it internally - it means you've got to be absolutely sure that you don't want to make significant changes to the API later, you've got to document it thoroughly etc.

I wouldn't be surprised to find a `TreeSet<T>` exposed in a future release, but it makes sense for MS to be cautious before making something public.

(I believe that `SortedSet<T>` in .NET 4 is basically a tree set, btw.)

Comment: You're right. SortedSet<T> Looks like a Red-Black BST. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Read the following article when you want to know how many Microsoft employees it actually takes to make this feature public: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx